# converting byte[] array to unsigned Long java

Tags: java, byte, long-integer, unsigned

Can you please answer this doubt related to java..

I would like to store `MAX_VALUE` of unsigned `long` (i.e 2(pow)64 -1)  a n byte array, and then read `byte[]` array to get back this `MAX_VALUE`.
As all data types are signed, so would like to know how to store 0xFF (each byte) value in each index of `byte[]` array i.e ignoring the signed bit. Please suggest on how to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no sign bit in 2's complement binary representation.

Comment: *"I would like to store `MAX_VALUE` of unsigned `long` (i.e 2(pow)64 -1) a n byte array"* Ok: `byte[] b = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}`

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
public class Utils {
    static byte[] longToByteArray(long value) {
        return ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(value).array();
    }

    static long byteArrayToLong(byte[] array) {
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(array).getLong();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long maxValue = Long.parseUnsignedLong("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", 16);
        byte[] b = longToByteArray(maxValue);
        System.out.println("b = " + Arrays.toString(b));

        long value = byteArrayToLong(b);
        System.out.println("value = " + value);
        System.out.println("hex value = " + Long.toUnsignedString(value, 16));
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a `ByteBuffer` is probably better than using `DataInputStream `/`DataOutputStream`. Less overhead and you have option of choosing big- vs little-endian mode.

Comment: Also, `"FFFFFFFF"` is only `MAX_UNSIGNED_INT`. You need double that, i.e. `"FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"` for `MAX_UNSIGNED_LONG`.

Comment: @Andreas absolutely. Fixed now. Not very used to ByteBuffer, so I hope this is the best way of using it.

Comment: No need for `LongBuffer`. Just use `putLong` and `getLong` on `ByteBuffer`, and you can chain it all: `return ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(value).array();` and `return ByteBuffer.wrap(array).getLong();`

Comment: And if you want Little Endian, you can add that to the chain, e.g. `return ByteBuffer.wrap(array).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getLong();`

Comment: Thanks again for these useful suggestions.